# Moving Posts and Users Only to New Site

Tags: theme-development

For several weeks my client has been working with me to finalize a major content and design change on his site. At the beginning of the process, I created a clone of his production site and that was what they worked on with me to upgrade their site. However, during this time, people have signed up on the production site and new posts, comments and media uploads have been added to the production site.

So, I have the new content (pages, media, etc) on a development site and new content (posts, users,etc) on a production site that I have to sync and I am asking for advice on how to accomplish moving all of the new users and posts to the dev site. Then I will clone the complete dev site as the production site.

Thank you in advance for any guidance.
Jon

Comment: Can't you just chose the items you want to export via Tools > Export and import them over to the development site?  After 3.0 I think that capability was built in.

Comment: Will the users, posts and comments stay synced?

Comment: I'm not 100% on that, I think so ... but if I were to test it I would create a new post under a "test" category, comment on it, and then export the posts from that category and move it over to the other site to see what happens.  That way, it's just a test post that doesn't really matter what happens to it.